# Distort multiple mesh on the same Sin wave path with Three.js and custom shaders

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader, trigonometry, vertex-shader

Im trying to create an effect where I have multiple images/meshes on the same sine wave. I can distort all separately, but of course they are not in sync.

In the vertex shader I have this line for the simple distortion:

`pos.z += sin(pos.y);`

My Idea would be to make the sin wave independent from the pos.y value and replace it with something like the current position y in the height of all of my images.

My other Idea would be to have only one mesh and paste every image on it, but I am not sure if it is a good practice or if that would work at all.

I would be greatful for any suggestion on how to implement this.

Thanks!

Comment: "Off course not sync?", what do you mean here? Synced with each other? Or sine wave? Why not use same axis then? "Independent of y" but then you said "replace with y". I am a bit confused.

Comment: Sorry if my problem is not clear. I draw a very simply demostration what I need.  https://imgur.com/a/fd8FsOj Basically I want them to continue the Sin wave.

Comment: Your need to cast position from local coordinates to world coordinates.

Comment: can you tell me an example how can I do that? Basically this is what I meant for my first idea, but I dont know how can I do that

Comment: Try this: vec3 wPos = vec3(modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));

Comment: It worked thank you very much! Do you mind adding some explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.  See this [example](http://philcrowther.com/WebGL/Flight/WaterTiles.html), which shows 4 adjacent grids in sync.  You have to adjust certain values to put them all in sync.  At present, I had been able to do so only in directions of 45 degree increments.  But you can use multiple waves of varying magnitudes and frequency.

The example was created using three.js code to perform the animation, but I have been able to replicate some of this using a shader.

Let me know if you still need help.